# Index on VARCHAR column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of 32,589 rows, and one of the columns is called 'Location' and is a `Varchar(40)` column type. The column holds a location, which is actually a suburb, all uppercase text.

A function that uses this table does a:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Location = 'A Suburb')
...
```

Would it be beneficial to add an index to this column, for efficiency? This is more a read-only table, so not much edits or inserts except for maintanance.

Comment: Probably so, but why don't you just try it?  Do some explains, see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an index SQL Server will have to perform a table scan to find the first instance of the location you're looking for. You might get lucky and have the value be in one of the first few rows, but it could be at row 32,000, which would be a waste of time. Adding an index only takes a few second and you'll probably see a big performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with @Brian Shamblen answer. 
Also, try using TOP 1 in the inner select

`IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable WHERE Location = 'A Suburb')`

You don't have to select all the records matching your criteria for `EXISTS`, one is enough.

Comment: `TOP 1` will give absolutely no improvement to query performance, because `EXISTS` already retrieve as little information as it can.

Answer (score 0):

An opportunistic approach to performance tuning is usually a bad idea.

To answer the specific question - if your function is using location in a where clause, and the table has more than a few hundred rows, and the values in the location column are not all identical, creating an index will speed up your function.

Whether you notice any difference is hard to say - there may be much bigger performance problems lurking in the database, and you might be fixing the wrong problem.